# Ubuntu: comando YUM en la versión 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, yum

Me gustaría consultar sobre el comando YUM para instalar un programa en la terminal de Ubuntu. En una máquina virtual instalé el SO y traté de instalar Oracle XE, siguiendo el tutorial de la misma página de Oracle me encontré con el error
"Command yum not found"

En varios portales encontré que se solucionaba instalando directamente son "sudo apt-get install yum", pero me encontraba con el error "Unable to locate package yum".

Soy demasiado principiante en Ubuntu y me preguntaba si podría ser por la versión del SO que tengo descargada o puede ser otro problema.

Comment: `yum` es un administrador de paquetes para distros basadas en RPM: Red Hat, Fedora, CentOS, Oracle Linux, etc. Ubuntu, Debian utilizan `apt` o `apt-get`. Así que, o instalas Oracle en Ubuntu con `apt`, o cambias a una distro basada en RPM. Y aún así `yum` ya es obsoleto, siendo reemplazado en las distros más recientes por `dnf`.